# Export and Import Shared Preferences in Flutter

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to export SharedPreferences to xml file and import xml file to be SharedPreference in Flutter? I have researched it and didn't get any result, most of the answers are written in Java. If it's possible, how do I do so? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why would need that? you may this package https://pub.dev/packages/xml_parser

Comment: @HasanAlyazidi I'd like to create an import and export feature so user can dynamically export/import their app preferences through devices, I will check the package first, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Use this package https://pub.dev/packages/xml to read and export xml files

Comment: Focus on exporting the xml file first, then parse the preferences from the xml then save them back to SharedPreferences, i hope you got the idea.

Comment: @HasanAlyazidi Yes, I got the idea now, thank you so much, it's very helping!

Answer (score 0):

Use getKeys to get all keys saved in shared preferences. Create an object with all keys and it's relevant values. Convert it to xml if required. Export json or xml. To import it back either use a file picker or manually add path. Convert XML to json if you have saved it as an xml file. Loop through each key and save it in shared preferences.